No SPI0 MISO pin on Raspberry PI 3B +
I had to reinstall my Raspberry Pi, now with Raspberry Pi OS bookworm, keeping the hardware. I am using a MCP3008 ADC converter with the new Adafruit libraries as https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-analog-to-digital-converters/mcp3008 isn't supported anymore.
So the new library uses Adafruit Blinka and according to https://learn.adafruit.com/mcp3008-spi-adc/python-circuitpython
The code is according to the Adafruit page above:
import time
import busio
import digitalio
import board
import adafruit_mcp3xxx.mcp3008 as MCP
from adafruit_mcp3xxx.analog_in import AnalogIn

spi     = busio.SPI(clock=board.SCK, MISO=board.MISO, MOSI=board.MOSI)
cs      = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D5)
mcp     = MCP.MCP3008(spi, cs)
channel = AnalogIn(mcp, MCP.P0)

while True:
    print(f"ADC Voltage: {voltage}")
    time.sleep(60)

I get all zero voltage, although I measure about 1 V at the analog input pin P0.
Using a logic analyzer I see that the MISO pin (channel 0) is stuck at High:

When I disconnect the ADC's Dout pin from the Raspi's SPI0_MISO GPIO9 I see the correct waveform:

I found that the SPI0 MISO isn't defined on the Pi using the pinctrl command, but the expected MISO pin on GPIO9 is defined as output being High. How can I get the MISO pin back to be on GPIO9?

I ran raspi-config setting disabling and then enabling spi. With pinctrl I saw the GPIO9 being correctly set as MISO. Yet, the program still returned 0. After reboot, the program still returned 0 and inspecting GPIO9 with pinctrl MISO is missing again and GPIO is defined as output High
Then I tried to change the GPIO in /boot/firmware/config.txt with this entry
gpio=9=a0

Yet, after reboot, the setting does not appear. Only after setting by pinctrl it works. Why is this and how can I run the pinctrl command at the end of boot?
pi@rp3b:~ $ sudo pinctrl get GPIO9 
 9: op -- -- | hi // GPIO9 = output
pi@rp3b:~ $ sudo pinctrl -e set GPIO9 a0
 9: a0    -- | lo // GPIO9 = SPI0_MISO
pi@rp3b:~ $ brightness.py
Raw ADC Value:  26137
13.09.2024 17:44:42 ADC Voltage: 1.31 V



Have you enabled SPI? On a normal Pi with this enabled pinctrl shows 9: a0    pd | lo // GPIO9 = SPI0_MISO 10: a0    pd | lo // GPIO10 = SPI0_MOSI 11: a0    pd | lo // GPIO11 = SPI0_SCLK  Frankly the idiosyncratic Adafruit code using their Circuit Python (no one else seems to use it) just seems attempt to hide the hardware interface and is inscrutable. The MCP3008 is a common chip and there are working examples in practically every library.

I have used the method in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608323/how-do-i-solve-error-externally-managed-environment-every-time-i-use-pip-3 : sudo mv /usr/lib/python3.11/EXTERNALLY-MANAGED .. to allow standard sudo pip

The blinkatest.py (see above) should have told me that spi is enabled, and yes it's enabled as signals on MOSI, SCLK and select are ok. Do you have a pointer to a MCP3008 library?

Most of my code is in c using my own libraries but the following is one of the simplest which uses the recommended gpiozero library (included in Raspberry Pi OS) https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_spi.html#gpiozero.AnalogInputDevice One simple example is https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html#measure-temperature-with-an-adc

Thanks. That code is much simpler. Yet, I still get 0 volts. I guess I need to redefine the GPIO as SPI0 MISO. How would I do that?

/boot/firmware/config.txt already has dtparam=spi=on and dtoverlay spi0-2cs did not change the GPIO9. Remember that GPIO10 SPI0_MOSI and GPIO11 SPI0_SCLK are ok.

I ran raspi-config setting disabling and then enabling spi. With pinctrl I saw the GPIO9 being correctly set as MISO. Yet, the program still returned 0. After reboot, the program still returned 0 and inspecting GPIO9 with pinctrl MISO is missing again and GPIO is defined as output High. (I have updated the question now with this)

The obvious conclusion is "the program" does not work. Did you TRY anything else?

See my answer, it's a workaround.

It turns out that after each reboot GPIO9 is defined as output high.
As adding gpio=9=a0 to file /boot/firmware/config.txt doesn't help I finally add to /etc/rc.local:
# Fix SPI MISO  not showing up on GPIO9
sudo /usr/bin/pinctrl -e set GPIO9 a0

That solved the problem, but still not sure why the GPIO9 is redefined during boot....
